# Including list view of relationship entity on update page

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am trying to extend an update view to include a list view of some related items below the edit form.

I have two models, Publishers and Volumes, which have a many to many relationship. What I am trying to do is this.... when a user clicks on the edit button for a publisher, I want them to go to a page with the standard edit fields, but also have a list view below the form that lists all of the volumes that are connected to that publisher via their relationship.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

As @tabacitu mentioned, Backpack doesn't currently have an built in solution for this. That said, this could maybe work for you:

This would allow you to use all functionality of the nested list view including interacting with the entities without conflicting at all with the parent

#### Step 1, Build your normal CRUDs

- Build out two normal CRUDs, one for Publishers, and one for Volumes

#### Step 2, Make a frameless layout

- copy `vendor/backpack/base/layout.blade.php`
- name it `frameless-layout.blade.php`
- remove `@include('backpack::inc.main_header')` and `@include('backpack::inc.sidebar')`

#### Step 3, Make a custom list view

- copy `vendor/backpack/crud/list.blade.php`
- name it `sub-list.blade.php`
- change the top line to `@extends('backpack::frameless-layout')`

#### Step 4, Make a custom field

- [Create a custom form field](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-fields#creating-a-custom-field-type) that contains an iFrame
- Inside your custom field template, have it set the url of the iFrame to the "list" url of the related resource
- You'd also need to utilize [List Filters](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-filters#filters-api) and a method for setting them dynamically so that the sub-list shows only the records related to the parent

#### Step 5, Configure and use the field

- In your crud controllers, use the `addField` to add the the configuration for the new field and its related model

Comment: Is it possible to instantiate a second crud object? Everything uses $this->crud, but it seems like it would probably work if I could create a second instance of that populated with the crud I wanted. Then I could just create a custom view that pulled in the code for the listview using the second crud object. Hope that's not a ridiculous question.

Comment: Definitely a valid question. I bet you could do just that. My only concern would be conflicts between the two CRUD's operations. For example, if the sub-crud allows editing of the records, when you click the "Edit" button in the sub-curd view, the entire page will navigate to the edit page for that CRUD's entity, leaving the parent CRUD behind. Using an iFrame would prevent that. But if you want only the list view and no other operations, a sub-crud object could work

Comment: Wow. Really nice solution.

Comment: Now the problem would be how to actually do that... lol. I will give it a try and let you know how it works out... thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there's no standard functionality to do that in Backpack. It's a pretty unusual way to do things. But it's not too difficult to achieve it.

If there aren't too many Vendors for one Publisher (as I expect it's the case here), I would keep it simple and NOT try to include the entire Backpack list view (with ajax, buttons, filters, etc) on top of the form. I would add a standard HTML table with the entries (and optionally buttons to Edit Vendor with target=_blank).

Here's how I would go about it:

1. In the Publisher CRUD, I would [use a custom view](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-api#custom-views) for the Edit operation; you can do that using `$this->crud->setEditView('edit_publisher_with_vendors')` in your `setup()` method;
2. In that custom edit view (`edit_publisher_with_vendors.blade.php` in my example), I would copy-paste everything inside [the edit.blade.php view that Backpack/CRUD is using](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/resources/views/edit.blade.php), and add a table with the Vendors on top of the Edit form; notice you have the current entry as `$entry` in this view; since there's a relationship on the model, you would be able to check if it has vendors using `$entry->vendors()->count()`, and get the vendors using `$entry->vendors`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. Your solution is a good stop gap for what i need right now, however, my parent entity has sometimes hundreds of related entities, so I still need to develop a method of providing a paginated and formatted table to display and navigate these items. I know that I can write a custom view to do so, it just would be easier if I could utilize the list view for those items within that edit page. Hopefully, I can figure out a way to do this.