# Edit related child models in Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

I've just recently started using Backpack and quite like it so far.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to allow create/update for related models in Laravel Backpack.

When there is a One-to-Many or even Many-to-Many relationship, we can use field type `relationship` and it works. We can create new child model using the inline feature.

However, the added child model is shown as a small tag with a cross icon only. We cannot see the details of this model and cannot edit it from that screen. It would be great if we could show the existing child models as a table with edit link that opens a modal. Is there any existing component that kind of does that?

If not, how can I go about achieving this?

Alternate approach: can I use the `table` field and somehow modify it so that data is saved as child models instead of json? I am happy to take either approach, whichever is better.

I hope I was able to articulate what I'm trying to achieve, I'm happy to use any other approach that is there or easier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like this might work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977461/including-list-view-of-relationship-entity-on-update-page/57022215#57022215 Its not the same scenario, but its similar

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've checked your suggestion in that page and keeping that as an option.

I noticed today there is a field type called `repeatable` and in the document, it says `selected entries will NOT be saved as usual, they will be saved as JSON; you can intercept the saving if you want and do whatever you want` - [link](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#repeatable).

I am curious on the **intercept** part and wondering if that can be used to tweak things a bit to what I need.